# what do I need to do to ensure "event" object is available for mousemove event handling?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This url provides a good example of a tooltip style implementation using D3 with SVG:

http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/1016860

However, for some reason, the following line is failing for me in my own custom implementation:

```
.on("mousemove", function(){return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(event.pageX+10)+"px");})
```

Specifically, with the following error:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageY' of undefined"
```

The region variable below exists and I'm able to bind mouseover and mouseout events to it:

```
d3.select(region)
    .on('mousemove', function(){return d3.select('#' + region.id + 'Hover').style("top", (event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(event.pageX+10)+"px");})
```

However binding to mousemove above fails because "event" is undefined.  In what scenario would "event" be unavailable?  Or maybe I should ask, what do I need to do to configure my code so that "event" will be available in this scenario?

Comment: I don't know much about d3, but shouldn't your event handlers take an `event` argument?

Comment: global `event` is an internet explorer non-standard abomination that Chrum recently adopted - event callbacks in real browsers take an argument, which is the event object you're looking for. What you could do is `function(e) { e = e || event; ... rest of your function` - so, for browsers that don't supply the event in the callback, you can use the global `event` - in your code, you then use `e` instead of `event`